# srec_cat "crop" output not retaining the original s19 file mapping format

Tags: crop, motorola, srecord, srec-cat

I need to crop the build binary(.S19) at a specific address. I tried using the command- “srec_cat infile.s19 −crop start_addr end_addr −o outfile.s19”.
The outfile.s19 is not retaining the original .s19 mapping(S315), getting outfile.s19 of "S325".

There are options to map explicitly.. But I can't prefer that due to other mapping (309) lines also there in-between.

Is there any way to retain the mapping of the original file(.s19) format after cropping?